# How to store and escape data in a web-application?

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml, escaping

I'm looking for the more formally correct and indipendent solution to store my data into my databases and web applications. I heard a lot of opinions in some months, but I'm not sure witch is correct. Planning to make my webapp more scalable I think that is more convenient to store the real and unescaped data in the database, are you agree with that?

Now I'm using this solution, an example with PHP5, XHTML and MySQLi pseudo-code.
I'm using everywhere **UTF-8** and **no magic_quotes**.

Data processing:

```
<?php
// catching data from a simple input form
$id_profile         = $_POST['id_profile'];
$details['name']        = $_POST['name'];
$details['text']            = $_POST['text'];

// filter $details
foreach($details as &$item) {   $item = trim($item); /* some stuff and other filters but no addslashes() */ }

// Preparing and doing the query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    UPDATE      profiles
    SET         name = ?, text = ?
    WHERE       id_profile = ?  ");
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $details['name'], $details['text'], $id_profile);
$stmt->execute();
// [...]
```

So in my database I have the real entered data no backslashed. Then when I need to output my text in a point of my page (included forms, tables, buttons, input, password fields and all DOM attributes) I use this little function to escape:

```
<?php

//a little escape function
function e($s) { return htmlentities($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); }

// Preparing and doing the query
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT      name, text
        FROM        profiles
        WHERE       id_profile = ?  ");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id_profile']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $text);

?>

<input type="text" id="name" value="<?=e($name) ?>"> <br />
<input type="text" id="text" value="<?=e($text) ?>"> <br />

<table>
<tr>
  <td><?=e($name) ?></td>
  <td><?=e($text) ?></td>
<td>
```

Is this correct, complete and secure? Some suggesions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension in PHP. This allows me to either wrap input parameters in PDO's `quote()` method:

```
$first_name = $this->pdo->quote($_POST['first_name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name) VALUES ('$first_name');
$res = $this->pdo->exec($sql);
...
```

Or use parameter substitution with prepared statements...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$smt = $this->pdo->prepare(array(
    $_POST['first_name'],
    $_POST['last_name'],
    $_POST['email']
));
```

When I'm fetching database records, I make sure strings are wrapped in `htmlspecialchars()` and integers are wrapped in `intval()`, although this probably isn't scalable. You'd want to create a function or method that selects your rows from a database and automatically applies any transformations for you. A quick and dirty example:

```
/**
 * @param string $table name
 * @param integer $id of record
 * @return array of returned objects
 * @abstract
 */
function select_from_db() {
    global $pdo;
    $id = intval($id);
    $row = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$id'";
    $res = $pdo->query($sql);
    while ($row = $res->fetchObject()) {
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            $row[$field] = htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }
    return $row;
}

// example usage:
$res = select_from_db('contacts', 1);
```

Comment: You think that I should use htmlspecialchars() instead htmlentities() ? Thanks!

Comment: Depends if you wanted all characters converting to entity equivalents. If used in the a wrapper function as above, you'd be able to substitute them at will and have those changes apply across your application though.